# jQuery show radiobutton if .length is more than 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a calendar where users can select 2 dates. A start date & an end date. The period between those 2 dates receives the class 'bookable-range'

The result I want is that when there are 5 or more classes 'bookable-range' a radio-button is shown & another one is hidden

**HTML-code**

Example of a field which is not selected, this is part of a table. The table shows every single day of the current month:

```
<td class=" bookable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="0" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a></td>
```

Example of a field which is part of range between the start & end date

```
<td class=" bookable-range" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="0" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a></td>
```

My javascript code which isn't working, I will have to trigger this code when the second click has happend, which I am not sure how to do.

```
var nights  = jQuery(".bookable-range").length;
if(nights >= 5){
  jQuery(".addon-436-transport-2-1").addClass("hidethis");
  jQuery(".addon-436-transport-2[]").addClass("active");
}
```

Demo of the page in case you need more html : http://riado.christophvh.be/nl/rooms/alaouite-kamer/

**Update**

current code provided in the answers. I made some mistakes with my css classes, which i corrected, but the code still doesn't work correctly. I don't get any of the console.log() messages.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".addon-wrap-436-transport-2-1").css('display', 'none');
  console.log(jQuery(".bookable-range").length);

  jQuery('table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr td').click(function(){
      console.log('day click');
      if(jQuery('.bookable-range').length >= 5){
          console.log('range found!');
          jQuery(".addon-wrap-436-transport-2-0").css('display','none');
          jQuery(".addon-wrap-436-transport-2-1").css('display','');
      }
  });
});
```

The following console.log gives back 0 even when i select a range of dates

```
console.log(jQuery(".bookable-range").length);
```

**Bounty Question:**
So i have to find where to put the code above( the place where the calculation of the range of selected days is made). But since this is code from the plugin i am using i don't know where to put it. I think it is located in following files, but i can't find the correct function:

**Datepicker.js** 
file of the plugin i am using:
http://pastebin.com/yvGzWVcj

**Booking-form.js**
http://pastebin.com/VgMUah2D

Comment: Search for errors on the console. The code posted is fine. Also check that events are firing properly.

Comment: no errors in the console, but i think this action is never triggered? And i'm not sure how to trigger it

Comment: Either use something like console.log() or alert() to check whether or not your code is working, or install firebug and place breakpoints. Also, since your jQuery is fine, are you sure your css is fine? I recommend using $.hide() and $.show() instead of making your own classes with display:none. Also, are you sure your .addon-... actually exists and is not subject to typo's and whatnot?

Comment: @A.Wolff that is part of my question, i don't know when to trigger it. The code might be correct but it is not triggered

Comment: how you generate your calendar to choose dates?

Comment: please put more client side code

Comment: @Christophvh I didnt get your actual question right away then, if all you want is to trigger that code, follow what the below answer says, only instead extend your existing function that adds the class "bookable-range" in such a way that it checks if there exist 5 of those after adding the class to the newly clicked element.

Comment: The calendar is generated by a wordpress plugin, also i think i can't use .hide() & .show() because i'm using bootstrap

Comment: @Christophvh I dont think bootstrap will affect  the way $.hide() and $.show() will work, though jQuery might interfere with your bootstrap if that is what you are scared of.

Comment: @Christophvh can you please put the html code of your table?

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar i added a link to the website itself, you can see the html code there, but i don't really think html is the issue here http://pastebin.com/t8sgbaKi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datepicker has a **onSelect** callback, ideally you'd use that. But it's already defined in the **settings**, the one in your pastebin file, called **wc_bookings_date_picker**. It is set to **select_date_trigger**, which you can't access once its being called, but you could modify it directly in the file and add your logic there.

You could also add it to this change event:

```
    jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'change', 
        '#wc_bookings_field_duration, #wc_bookings_field_resource', 
         function(){
             console.log(jQuery('.bookable-range').length)
         });
```

Comment: works great! thank you very much! You will receive the bounty the moment i can use it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check if there is a range of days every time there's a click in the calendar. You can change the css instead of using the hide & show functions of JQuery:

```
JQuery(document).ready(function(){
    JQuery('table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr td').click(function(){
        console.log('day click');
        if(JQuery('.bookable-range').length >= 5){
            console.log('range found!');
            JQuery(".addon-436-transport-2-1").css('display','none');
            JQuery(".addon-436-transport-2[]").css('display','');
        }
    });
};
```

As the comment suggests, there is already a handler for the calendar days. To avoid having 2 handlers for the same event you can copy the code that checks the range inside the first handler:

```
function selectDay(day){

    //some code...

    if(JQuery('.bookable-range').length >= 5){
        console.log('range found!');
        JQuery(".addon-436-transport-2-1").css('display','none');
        JQuery(".addon-436-transport-2[]").css('display','');
    }
}
```

Comment: The html shows that op is using some function called selectDay, you should probably update your answer to work with that, wouldn't make sense two have 2 click handlers, but your answer is correct

Comment: I mean, the jquery might be incorrect, I didn't test it, though conceptually the answer is right, which is really the point wouldn't you agree? Im sure OP could debug his way out of some javascript errors.

Comment: thank you for your answer, if i paste your code in my console it will show a log, but i'm my code nothing is happening, do i have to wrap it in document.ready() or something?

Comment: @Christophvh if the log is showing "range found!", then your css / html is not written correctly.

Comment: Yes, you shoul wrap the first code (the click event) in "JQuery(document).ready(function(){ /* event binding here */ })". You can check if something is selected with console.log(JQuery(".addon-436-transport-2-1").length);, if its 0 it means JQuery can't find anything with class "addon-436-transport-2-1".

Comment: @AleixValls , your code returns 1 so it is selecting

Comment: @Christophvh do you see "range found!" in the javascript console? If the message is not showing you can check how many day are found using "console.log(JQuery(".bookable-range").length);", it should by >= 5.

Comment: @AleixValls , that results in 0, so that part isn't working, i updated my question with my current code

Comment: @Christophvh you should execute the code that checks for the range when you have a range selected, otherwise it will always return 0.

Comment: @AleixValls to be honest, i really can't find where that is handled, this is the datepicker.js file http://pastebin.com/yvGzWVcj